# select specific numbers out of array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

this might be a very basic question. But I would like to know how I can select specific elements out of an array.
I have an array with `100` elements:

```
var cubes = [element1, element2, element3 ...]
```

and I would like to select lets say element `25-35`.

I tried something like:

`cubes[25-35].somefunction();`
or `cubes[25,26,27,28].somefunction();`

but both does not work. How to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to slice the array by indices and then iterate over the elements in the result array and call the function on each element:

```
cubes.slice(25, 35).forEach(somefunction);
```

This assumes `forEach` is supported.

Otherwise,

```
var newArray = cubes.slice(25, 35);
for (var i=0; i < newArray.length; i++) {
   newArray[i].someFunction();
}
```

Finally, if even `slice` isn't available:

```
for (var i=firstIndex; i <= lastIndex; i++) {
       cubes[i].someFunction();
}
```

Comment: honestly it gives me `newArray is undefined` with your second example.

Comment: Did it complain about slice? Are you sure the array has indices 25-35? It is quite possible the code needs to be tweaked for your situation.

Comment: Once you verify the array is populated with all the objects you expect (which is important), then just try for (var i=firstIndex; i <= lastIndex; i++) { cubes[i].someFunction() } Back to basics.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Added the most basic solution to the answer. An accept or at least an upvote never hurt anyone haha.

Comment: and theres definitely no possibility to select more specific elements in one argument like: `cubes[1,5,9,50,98].somefunction()`. Despite the count from 25-35 (which is already solved)
so i have to write: `cubes[1].somefunction()` `cubes[5].somefunction()`and so on.

Answer (score 4):

```
cubes.slice(25, 35).somefunction();
```

Comment: this does not work. I'm using it like this `cubes.slide(25, 35).hide();` but it throws me a console alert that the function is not defined.

Comment: Indeed, as I mentioned in my answer, you need to call the function on the elements of the array, not the array itself. Something like what I posted should work if the objects in the array have a hide function.